# jQuery Keycode help

Tags: jquery, keycode

How could I run a simple function when a key is pressed using jQuery. So for example if a user pressed the 'Q' key which is 81 in JavaScript it would run a function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you want to do this when you're on a particular textbox, or on a page?

You could do this for the page (Which I suspect is what you want)

```
$(function(){
   $(document).keypress(function(event){
     if(e.charCode==81){
        callMyFunction();
     }
   });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).bind('keypress', function(event) {
    switch(e.which) {
        case 81: {
           alert('Q!');
           break;
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One approach:

```
$(window).keydown(
    function(e){
        if (e.keyCode == 113 || e.keyCode == 81) { // 113 = q, 81 = Q
            // do this
        }
    });
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/X6LxY/)

jQuery API references:

- [`keydown()`](http://api.jquery.com/keydown/)